# Convert string to boolean for checkbox

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I use **v-model** to display checked/unchecked checkboxes:

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in myFields">
  <v-checkbox
     v-model="myArray[item.code]"
     :label="item.name"       
   />
</template>
```

It works fine when I get true or false values from API. But now I get strings: "true" or "false" and my checkbox is always checked.
If I change the code on:

```
v-model="Boolean(myArray[item.code])"
```

I got the error:

> 'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying `Boolean(myArray[item.code])` won’t work anyway because the string `'false'` is `true`. So `Boolean('false')` return `true`.

Instead you should do `myArray[item.code] !== 'false'`
`'false'` will return `false` and every other string than false will return `true`

EDIT: You need to change myArray to an array of boolean like so

```js
myArray.map((element) => element !== 'false')
```

Then this code will work

```html
<template v-for="(item, index) in myFields">
  <v-checkbox
     v-model="myArray[item.code]"
     :label="item.name"       
   />
</template>
```

Comment: No, I get error: " 'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS.", so we can't use expression in v-model